# How to read a bone's quaternion rotation and convert from local bone to world space

Tags: python, animation, export, mathematics

I am writing a custom exporter to export from blender to my opengl program.
To read the roatation, as well as convert from blender's cordinate system to my game's system, i use this code:

```
e = poseBone.rotation_quaternion.to_euler()
quat = Euler((e[1], e[2], e[0])).to_quaternion() #write this quat to file
```

Bones in blender, as demonstrated by this image, have their own local space:
[image]
I believe this difference in local bone space vs world space is the last thing causing incorrect rotations in my opengl program. How would convert bone.rotation_quaternion from local bone to world space prior to export? I have seen several similar questions, but none that helped me.

Comment: It is quite confusing that you take the `rotation_quaternion` and convert it to an euler and back to quaternion in an VERY roundabout method.

Comment: This is to convert from blender's coordinate system to my own. X->Z, Y->X Z->Y

Answer (score 2):

Based on some simple experiments it seems that

```
debone = Matrix([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,-1,0], [0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]) #because bones are wacky
m = armature_object.matrix_world * poseBone.matrix * debone
o2.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
o2.location, o2.rotation_quaternion, o2.scale = m.decompose()
```

will align `o2` with `poseBone` (unless o2 has a parent causing its matrix_local to not be identical to matrix_world)

Comment: I am trying to convert rotation from bone space to object/world space. If i "roll" the pose bone 90 degrees along itself, poseBone.matrix.to_euler() or poseBone.rotation_quaternion.to_euler() says the rotation is around Y, becouse in bone space, "Y" is the axis that runs along the bone. However, unless the bone itself is aligned with world "Y", then the rotation will be wrong. For excample, if the bone is aligned with "X" then the rotation will bend the animation up/down instead of rolling it.

Comment: OK, let's see if my edit to the answer gives you what you need.

Comment: with this code, rotation_quaternion.to_euler() gives a rotation of 90 for blender's 'X' and -90 for 'Z' when the bone is in its original position.

Comment: Would a debone matrix of `Matrix([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0], [0,-1,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]) ` be better?  I am having difficulty figuring out exactly what you want from the wording of your question.

Comment: I am just trying to get the rotation from resting position at a given key frame. armature.pose.bones[foo].matrix * armature.data.bones [foo].matrix_local.to_4x4().inverted() seems to be giving something along the correct lines,  but I need to do more testing.

Comment: i understand my language may be a little vague, so to help illustrate my point: https://i.imgur.com/aQAOOCc.png shows the local bone axis, bone rotations are in this space. I want the rotations in local space, which would be this: https://i.imgur.com/TXR6G9E.png A 90 deg rotation around Z only works if bone Z and world Z are aligned, and bone Y with bone X.

Comment: " I want the rotations in local space" should be " I want the rotations in global space". (No edits after 5 minutes allowed)

Comment: 1) create a .blend file containing an armature with a pose and a suzanne (monkey mesh) that is approximately in the desired position relative to the bone 2) upload that .blend file to blendexchange and link it to this question.  3) Once that is done I can try to come up with the math necessary to calculate suzanne's exact matrix from the bone's pose.

Comment: Look at the blender's standard bvh file exporter (addons\io_anim_bvh). It does exactly what you want. To get the bone rotation it adds all the parent bones' rotations up along the tree.